# New class object retaining value of an object defined previously

Tags: python-2.7, oop

```
s1 = Student()
s1.set_access_token(TOKEN)
s1.set_api_key(CLIENT_API_KEY)
s1.get_role(pagination_range=(2, 3))
pprint(s1.get_response())

s2 = Student()
s2.set_access_token(TOKEN)
s2.set_api_key(CLIENT_API_KEY)
s2.get_role(role_id="0c127e7b-3b97-4d9d-a802-5acbca54097a")
pprint(s2.get_response())
```

There is a `Student` class which has 6 member variables that are `None` by default. As given above, the object `s1` sets `pagination_range` to `(2, 3)` and `s2` sets `role_id` to `0c127e7b-3b97-4d9d-a802-5acbca54097a`.

But I notice that the value of `pagination_range` in `s2` was also set to `(2, 3)`.

Other information that might be useful is:

- `Student` is child class of a `Role` class.
- `Role` uses the `requests` module to send requests using the values given in the code snippet above

Here is the [Student](https://github.com/apanimesh061/hmhco-client/blob/master/hmhapi/v3/Indentity/roles.py#L8) class and here is the [Role](https://github.com/apanimesh061/hmhco-client/blob/master/hmhapi/v3/Indentity/identity2.py#L7) class.

How to avoid that?

Comment: Are you sure that pagination_range and role_id are instance fields and not class members? How do they get defined initially? Also, are the setter members defined as instance members or classmethods? It would probably help to see the source for the Student class.

Comment: @sisyphus I have added links to codes.

Answer (score 0):

api_key is defined as a class variable in Role...

```
class Role(object):
    response = None
    access_token = None
    api_key = None
```

These fields are defined outside of the initialiser and so aren't qualified by a 'self' instance - so they're defined against the class itself. This means that all instances of the class share the same value.

You probably need to define them against an instance in the **init** method...

```
class Role(object):
    def __init__(self):
        response = None
        access_token = None
        api_key = None
```

Of course, you might be able to get away with do that just for api_key. It depends on what the other fields are used for.